# Is it possible to "make something work" while virtualbox is in "save state" mode?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to make some app working, while virtualbox is in "save state" mode.

Is it possible ? And if yes, please describe a little how can I do that ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember my VBox correctly, the "save state" mode (called "suspend" in VMware) is equivalent to a bare-bones computer's Hibernate mode if I remember right.

On a bare-bones system installation, WoL (Wake on LAN) and a few special BIOS-level things can still operate in Standby or Hibernate mode.

The difference about VMs from a bare-bones system, though, is that they don't have those types of capabilities.  During a "save state" mode, or a VM put into "standby" on VMware, nothing running in the virtual guest works, because the system is 'frozen' like Hibernate does.  There's no way for such states to permit programs/applications to operate in a guest operating system in a 'frozen' state.  Just like a computer in "hibernate" mode, on which none of its services will operate.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to run any app when the VM is in save state.
Save state is equivalent of sleep option in OS. This is what the official manual says,

VirtualBox "freezes" the virtual machine by completely saving its state to your local disk.

When you start the VM again later, you will find that the VM continues exactly where it was left off. All your programs will still be open, and your computer resumes operation. Saving the state of a virtual machine is thus in some ways similar to suspending a laptop computer (e.g. by closing its lid).

If you consider running an app and want less overhead then look at the option of headless mode. I am not sure headless mode available for Windows. I used run ubuntu and other linux/unix OS on headless mode, which saves considerable amount of RAM usage. Please look at [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) link for headless mode setup and usage.